# Getting the Text of ToolstripItem in a ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, .net, contextmenu, toolstrip

I have a contextmenustrip for a DGV. It has a toolstripitem called "ChangeTo" and this branches out into a set of items that are created dynamically based on the config file used. When I run the program that Has Rt-Click -> Change To -> (List of Items)

When I click any item from the drop down list in the contextmenustrip , I want the selected row of the DGV to change to the text in the list...

For this i need to get the 'Text' associated with the toolstripitem. How can i do this? 
I cant just use toolstripitemname.text coz i wouldnt know the item name until runtime... I tried using

```
ChangeTotoolstripitem.DropDown.Items...
```

but i need the index...

This is the function i use when the item is clicked

```
private void changeTypeToToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this not work as you have the ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs?:

```
string toolstripItemName = e.ClickedItem.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
private void changeTypeToToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
   string clickedtext=e.ClickedItem.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to read this a few times, but I think this is what you are after:

```
private void changeTypeToToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e) {
  ToolStripMenuItem mi = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
  if (mi != null) {
    // This is your text:
    Console.WriteLine(mi.Text);
  }
}
```

Is that what you are after? You could just as easily get the control's name (`mi.Name`) or whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

```
ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;
Console.WriteLine("++ clicked item ->{0}[{1}]  of {2}", item.Name, item.Text, item.Owner.Name);
```